# Keeping the ending 0 after two decimal places for default user input value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I'm make a react application that takes an input that should be shown to two decimal places. When I have a number that has a 0 in the second decimal place it is removing it. I notice it does this as soon as the string gets converted to a number.

This is how the input looks when first loaded. The preferred display would be 1.60 (two decimal places)

[image]

```js
function ProductMaterial() {
        const [name, setName] = useState("");

        function handleChange(e) {
            let val = e.target.value;
            //ignore values entered after 2 decimal places
            if (val.includes(".") && val.split(".")[1].length > 2) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                setName(parseFloat(val));
                setMaterialState(parseFloat(val));
            }

            calcTotal();
            setTotal(product.id, product.total);
        }

        function handlePress(e) {
            let val = e.target.value;
            //ignore values entered after 2 decimal places.
            //For some reason it needs to be compared to 1 for it to work with 0s.
            if (val.includes(".") && val.split(".")[1].length > 1) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                setName(parseFloat(val));
                setMaterialState(parseFloat(val));
            }

            calcTotal();
            setTotal(product.id, product.total);
        }

        return (
            <div className="input-group-sm col-xs-2 input-group">
                <div className="input-group-prepend">
                    <span className="input-group-text">$</span>
                </div>
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    type="number"
                    min="0.00"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onKeyPress={handlePress}
                    value={product.material}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Here is the code for setMaterialState. It changes the product.material value, and then calls `setMaterial()` in a `useEffect()` function. The `setMaterial()` takes the id of the product, and the new material value and saves it to state. Product.material needs to be a number for this for other calculations that happen.

```js
    function setMaterialState(newMaterial) {
        product.material = newMaterial;
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setMaterial(product.id, product.material);
    }, [product.material]);
```

I'm struggling on the forcing it to be two decimal places when there is a 0 at the end. I'm realizing that the issue with not starting doing 1.60 is due to it being converted to a float value and not being a string. I tried doing a `UseEffect() []`, but it seems like the only way to force the two decimal places is keeping it as a string or converting it to a string by using `product.material.toFixed(2)`. Right now value in the input `value={product.material}` needs to be a number to correctly execute calculations and collect user input. I'm not sure what the best solution for this is.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) object is one approach you could try.

```
function ExampleComponent() {
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState("0.00");

  // you can `parseFloat` the string back into a number
  // where needed (e.g., calculations)
  function handleChange(e) {
    let number = e.target.value;
    setInputVal(number);
  }

  // applies formatting when input has lost focus
  function formatValue(e) {
    if (inputVal) {
      const locale = "en-US";
      setInputVal(
        new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2,
          maximumFractionDigits: 2,
          useGrouping: false, // commas will break `parseFloat`
        }).format(parseFloat(inputVal))
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>${inputVal ? inputVal : "0.00"}</p>
      <input
        type="number"
        min="0"
        step="0.01"
        onChange={handleChange}
        onBlur={formatValue}
        value={inputVal}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Link to a working example:
[codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-hypatia-omsmzi](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-hypatia-omsmzi?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like price is still a string and is the same as using `.toFixed(2)`.

Comment: @Betsy What about converting the string to a float first? E.g., `parseFloat("1.6")` (or I think I might be misunderstanding the question and you need an actual number type?)

Comment: The input doesn't seem to work when I use this method. It displays properly but cannot be modified. I assume because {price} is a string value and the input can't get updated with the handleChange code I have. I'm trying to implement but I don't see a way for it to work.

Comment: @Betsy I'm pretty sure that has nothing to do with string vs number, which would not cause the behavior you describe. You're treating the input as both a controlled and uncontrolled component: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Comment: @Betsy The `input` in my updated example can now be modified. Formatting needed to be moved to a `blur` event.